# Twitter bootstrap code highlight

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, syntax-highlighting

I'm new to Twitter bootstrap and I really enjoy the use of it. However, I seem to have one particular problem with the code highlighting.

I have a big piece of HTML code that I would like to fit in a pre to highlight the code. However, when I paste in the HTML code it doesn't show the HTML code, but just renders the code and shows the styled code. [Click here for screenshot](http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/626/codepd.jpg)

The code I use: http://pastebin.com/b0BsAi2i

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the html characters. You can do this in PHP by using the htmlspecialchars() function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

There are also a few websites that can do this for you such as http://www.string-functions.com/htmlencode.aspx/htmlencode.aspx

Your code then becomes:

```
<pre class="prettyprint linenums">
&lt;h1&gt;SHOP4STARTUP&lt;/h1&gt;
</pre>
```